# Adding multiple columns in one migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

Scenario: we already have a *Document* model, and we want to add

- *public*
- *private*

or more columns using a single migration.

From what I've searched and read so far, you just have to edit the migration file. If the migration was already applied, roll back and migrate again.

1. Is this the common best practice, or is there a better way?
2. If this is the way to do it, what would a proper naming for that migration be?

Comment: Those are pretty terrible variable names to use in just about any programming language due to the fact that they're usually keywords.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Rolling back a migration and re-editing it is only safe if that migration is local and has not been pushed out to any repository. Editing a migration that others have applied may cause issues.

The safest way to add columns to an existing table is to just create a new migration:

```
rails g migration add_public_and_private_to_document public:string private:string
```

If you use the `add_[column_names]_to_[model]` naming convention, rails will work out the appropriate table and create the migration you want.

Have a read here for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 2):

@Cam way is rigth..Except you will need to update two things after running the migration.

So , let us say I have an existing scaffold called `myapp` and I want to add more fields to that scaffold . Three things to  done .

The field to be added are :

=>

1) `rails g migration add_term_count_and_current_record_count_and_previous_record_count_to_myapp term_count:integer , current_record_count:integer , previous_record_count:integer`

=>

```
2) Update views, example updating _form.html.rb
```

I needed to add :

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_record_count %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :current_record_count%>
  </div>

 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_record_count %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :previouse_record_count%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :term_count  %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :terminations_count %>
  </div>
```

=>

```
3) Update Controller :
```

New versions of rails has what is called strong parameter to prevent hackers from passing arbitrary column field values. Long story short , update the method with the new fields names , otherwise you will not see the new fields.

```
 # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.

def vendor_file_params
    params.require(:vendor_file).permit(:name, :run_date,  :term_count ,
    :current_record_count , :previous_record_count ,:comments)   
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can issue the command like this:

**rails g migration document public:string private:string**